# Caliburn Micro - Display a name on a tab control - Beginner issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

References

Github project [CMTabNavigation](https://github.com/JeanMarcFlamand/C.M-Basic-Examples/tree/master/CMTabNavigation)

TargetFramework netcoreapp3.0

PackageReference Caliburn.Micro Version="4.0.105-alpha"

I'm doing my first example to show ViewModel in a tab control when user click a menu item.
The example works fine but the display name on the tab not working. Can you help me

```
<Window x:Class="CMTabNav.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMTabNav.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="25">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem.Background>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFC3C1AD" Offset="0.105"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </MenuItem.Background>
                <MenuItem x:Name="PartsList" Header="_Parts List" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="AssembliesList" Header="_Assembly List" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="Demo" Header="_Demo" />
                <MenuItem x:Name="ExitApplication" Header="_Exit" />
            </MenuItem>

        </Menu>
        <Grid>
            <TabControl x:Name="Items">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                            <Button Content="X"  
                                cal:Message.Attach="DeactivateItemAndTryClose($dataContext, 'true')" />

                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            </TabControl>


            <!--<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Margin="20 5 20 20">

            </ContentControl>-->
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

ShellViewModel.cs

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace CMTabNav.ViewModels
{
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {

        }

        public void PartsList()
        {

            ActivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<PartsListViewModel>(), new CancellationToken());
             DisplayName = "Part List";

        }
        public void AssembliesList() //AssembliesList
        {
            ActivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<AssembliesListViewModel>(), new CancellationToken());
            DisplayName = "Assembly List";
        }
        public void Demo()
        {
            ActivateItemAsync(IoC.Get<DemoViewModel>(), new CancellationToken());
            DisplayName = "Demo View";
        }
        public async Task DeactivateItemAndTryClose(IScreen item, bool close)
        {
            await DeactivateItemAsync(item, close, new CancellationToken());
        }


    }
}
```

PartsListViewModel.cs

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CMTabNav.ViewModels
{
    class PartsListViewModel: Screen
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you inherit VMs from `Screen` class?

Comment: I do not have an answer yet because I'm in a huge learning process. I did build this example base on Tim Corey course "TimCo Retail Manage" on youtube. Sorry I do no catch everything yet in that course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your view models to inherit `PropertyChangedBase` class and implement `IHaveDisplayName` interface, like this

```cs
class PartsListViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IHaveDisplayName
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

According to your data template, `DisplayName` should be declared in data context of tab item itself (`PartsListViewModel`,`DemoViewModel`, etc.) , not in `ShellViewModel`. You should set the display name before activating any view model

```cs
public void PartsList()
{
    var partsListViewModel = IoC.Get<PartsListViewModel>();
    partsListViewModel.DisplayName = "Part List";
    ActivateItemAsync(partsListViewModel, new CancellationToken());
}
```

You also should update `DeactivateItemAndTryClose` method and pass a different type parameter instead of `IScreen`

```cs
public async Task DeactivateItemAndTryClose(PropertyChangedBase item, bool close)
{
    await DeactivateItemAsync(item, close, new CancellationToken());
}
```

However, you can leave your view models as is, inheriting `Screen` class, only properly set the `DisplayName` for every view model before activation, as it shown in `PartsList()` method above

Comment: Thank for the input. I will look at it later

Comment: The proposed change to inherit PropertyChangedBase class and implement IHaveDisplayName on all ViewModel works fine. Thanks Pavel. The inheriting Screen class solution not working yet. I need to look at it why. Best regards